# Using surf in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, matlab-figure, surface

I have two variables say `X`,`Y`.  `X,Y` are each`5*1` matrices.
Each row represent a particular person and `X` and `Y` are two variables that represent two characteristics.
I have combined  the effect of `X,Y` through certain operations to form `Z` so Z is also a 5*1 matrix.

Now I want to plot `X,Y,Z`. That is I want to plot (X1,Y1,Z1),(X2,Y2,Z2),...(X5,Y5,Z5)

This is what I did.

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(X,Y)
z=diag(Z)
surf(x,y,z)
```

I want to know does this plot points such as (X1,Y2,Z2),(X1,Y3,Z2)(X2,Y1,Z3).
Because I **don't** want to plot these as I want to plot each **individual** person and **not** combining people.

Comment: Do you want to plot a grid or just the points in a 3d plot?

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess that what you want is a 3d plot of your 5 persons. This will plot the 5 points individually.

```
plot3(X,Y,Z,'ro')
```

You can color the values according to the `Z` values by using `scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)`. Where `S` is representing the size and `C` the color.

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,20,Z)
colormap default
```

To answer your other question. `[x,y]=meshgrid(X,Y)` will generate two fields which represent every combination of `X` and `Y`. With `z = diag(Z)` you have a diagonal Matrix. Therefore the points you plot are `(X1,Y1,Z1),(X1,Y2,0), ... (X2,Y1,0),(X2,Y2,Z2),(X2,Y3,0) ...`
So you will plot all posibilities of `X` and `Y` but set the `Z` value to zero if the indexes of `X`and `Y` don't match.

Using `surf` will then create a plane over these points.

Comment: I want a 3d plot using `surf`. I want to see the change of `z` from colors. If I set the `z` value to 0 when `x` and `y ` do not  match doesn't it still plot value `0`

Comment: I wrote the following function `function f=plotting(x,y,z1)
    z=zeros(length(x),length(y));
    for i=1:length(x)
        for j=1:length(y)
            if(i ~=j)
                z(i,j)=NaN;
            else
                z(i,j)=z1(i);
            end
        end
        f=z;
    end
    ` Then I used `T=plotting(X,Y,Z) ` `surf(x,y,T)` But it doesn't plot any graph. Is it because it has so many `NaN` values

Comment: This happens because `surf` is a function that plots a plane over a grid. The diagonal matrix is no grid, as there are no neighboring elements to the diagonal elements. Can you elaborate how the desired output should look? 

Edit: you can write `z(~eye(length(x))) = NaN;` to avoid the loops.

Comment: I edited my post to show you a method to color the individual points.